# Привязка клавиатуры к button с изменением свойства на IsPressed и обратно

Tags: c#, wpf

Знатоки подскажите

Делаю привязку на button к клавиатуре:

```
if (e.Key == Key.R)
{
    btn1.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
}
```

Все работает, но у меня кнопка имеет свой стиль с элементом визуализации нажатия, которое не хочет отображаться.
Пробовал так:

```
if (e.Key == Key.R)
{
    btn1.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
    typeof (Button).GetMethod("set_IsPressed", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).Invoke(btn1, new object[] {true});
```

Триггер меняется и остается нажатым
Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку клавиатуры срабатывало свойство `IsPressed` а при отжатии менялось обратно?

Comment: какое именно событие обрабатываете? ну когда проверяете if (e.Key == Key.R) ?

Comment: Window_KeyDown -  Я привязываю к каждой кнопке нажатие определенной клавиши

Comment: Подпишитесь на событие KeyUp и вызывайте необходимый метод. К тому же, не рекомендую изменять значений свойств с помощью конструкции которую Вы применяете. Лучше используйте typeof(Button).GetProperty("IsPressed", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic).SetValue(btn1, new object[] { true }, null);

Comment: Хорошо, попробую что либо предпринять

Comment: @Geslot Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.